Enabling the Animations Module in Angular 18
I wish to enable to Animations Module in Angular 18 to build a little app where the user clicks a button and a div moves across the screen. I don't know how to follow the documentation here.
enter image description here
What file is that?
I tried understanding but I couldn't

angular ALWAYS execute the file main.ts (really execute the file you indicate in the file angular.json in
 projects-->ClientApp-->architect-->build-->options-->main

If you have an Angular app use Modules in your main.ts you have some like
//when we use modules
//see that you "bootstrap" a Module
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

If you use standalone you can see in your main.ts some like
//when you use standalone components
//see that you "bootstrap" a component
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent)

Well, when you can use animations, or httpClient or routers and you use standalone component you need add as providers when "bootstrap" the component (replace the before sentence by)
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideAnimationsAsync(),
    provideRouter(APP_ROUTES),
    ...
  ]
}

remmeber also import the function providerAnimationsAsync, or provideAnimations or provideRouter
NOTE: Generally we use also the main.ts to define the main.component (and we can add also more components in this file -it's not recomended-)
